# Snapdragon 820 Adreno 530 doesn't return correct device info

Tags: opencl, device, qualcomm

I am trying to get CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS and CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY device info from Adreno 530 GPU on Snapdragon 820 device (Samsung Galaxy S7). But, I get 4 for CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS and 1 for CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY. This seems to be wrong because CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY = 1 means 1 MHz. Following is my code to extract these information:

```
cl_uint buf_uint;
clGetDeviceInfo(device.get(), CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(buf_uint), &buf_uint, NULL);
printf("  DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS = %u\n", (unsigned int)buf_uint);
clGetDeviceInfo(device.get(), CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(buf_uint), &buf_uint, NULL);
printf("  DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY = %u\n", (unsigned int)buf_uint);
```

Note: device is of type cl::Device.

For Mac, it seems to correctly working. I get 40 compute units and 1200 MHz clock frequency for Intel Iris Pro.

Comment: After running my own example and also using the OpenCL-Z tool on my Galaxy S8 I can confirm those two values are 4 and 1... I feel this **has** to be a bug on the Qualcomm OpenCL driver or something

Comment: Thanks @FrickeFresh for confirming. I suspect Qualcomm don't want to reveal this information :) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on SDM665 SDM845 ...,

```
[INFO][OCL INFO] DEVICE MAX CLOCK FREQUENCY (1) MHz
```

I suspect Qualcomm don't want to reveal this secret...

```
[INFO][OCL INFO] OPENCL DEVICE BASIC INFO:
[INFO][OCL INFO] CL_DEVICE_TYPE : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
[INFO][OCL INFO] CL_DEVICE_NAME : QUALCOMM Adreno(TM)
[INFO][OCL INFO] CL_DEVICE_VENDOR       : QUALCOMM
[INFO][OCL INFO] CL_DEVICE_VERSION      : OpenCL 2.0 Adreno(TM) 610
[INFO][OCL INFO] CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION     : OpenCL C 2.0 Adreno(TM) 610
[INFO][OCL INFO] CL_DEVICE_PROFILE      : FULL_PROFILE
[INFO][OCL INFO] CL_DRIVER_VERSION      : OpenCL 2.0 QUALCOMM build: commit #03e27f8 changeid #I326e6aff90 Date: 11/02/20 Mon Local Branch: mybrancheb1d781c-1a78-f1f4-8c78-ac1f6bcc2cee Remote Branch: quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r116-rel Compiler E031.37.12.02

[INFO][OCL INFO] OPENCL DEVICE PERFORMANCE INFO:
[INFO][OCL INFO] DEVICE ADDRESS BITS (64) bits
[INFO][OCL INFO] DEVICE MAX CLOCK FREQUENCY (1) MHz
[INFO][OCL INFO] DEVICE MAX COMPUTE UNITS (1) IN ONE DEVICE
```